# 404 error in Spring MVC using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I made a simple form with Spring MVC but I keep getting 404 error, I looked up in every similar topic with no result, here is my code :

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringMVCsample2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>student.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.capgemini.springtest2" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>


</beans>
```

the StudentController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

      return "result";
   }
}
```

result.jsp file :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>${name}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>${age}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>${id}</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

student.jsp file :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

student is a normal bean, and the and the jsps are simple forms.

the following picture represents the structure of my program :

[image]

Comment: You didn't even mention what URL you're trying to access.

Comment: Post your `jsp`, please

Comment: @kryger http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCsample2/ and http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCsample2/student  , none of them works

Comment: @romach I editted the post to add them

Comment: right click on project --> properties --> Web project Settings, make sure your context root is SpringMVCsample2

Comment: Can you try change the prefix property of viewResolver to <property name="prefix" value="/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/" />

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `action` attribute of the form in your `student.jsp` to `/addStudent`:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addStudent">
```

Answer (score 0):

if your contextpath is SpringMVCsample2, then try below:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="SpringWeb" action="/SpringMVCsample2/addStudent">
```

> http://www.catchmycity.com/tutorial/spring-framework-spring-form-handling-using-modelattribute-bean-and-commandname-attribute_46